# Information on my DS-160 form and the embassy website do not match

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas

The information on my DS-160 form and the embassy website do not match. On my DS-160 form, the type of visa I have is B1/B2, but on the embassy website it says I have an F-1 student visa, and my appointment is in five days.

Can I change the information on the DS-160 form, since it has been more than thirty days since I created it? Also, can I change the information when I go for my appointment, or will that cause me to be refused?

Comment: Which visa are you actually applying for?

Comment: I am applying for an F-1 visa

Comment: How did the embassy site know you were applying for an F-1?  And when you filled out your DS-160 (and I have no clue about this) did you state you were going to be studying?

Comment: No I was applying for a B-1 before COVID and used the same DS-160 to apply for an F-1 on the embassy site